# Can’t download YouTube video

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, urllib

I’m having trouble retrieving the YouTube video automatically. Here’s the code. The problem is the last part. `download = urllib.request.urlopen(download_url).read()`

```
# YouTube video download script
# 10n1z3d[at]w[dot]cn

import urllib.request
import sys

print("\n--------------------------")
print (" YouTube Video Downloader")
print ("--------------------------\n")

try:
    video_url = sys.argv[1]
except:
    video_url = input('[+] Enter video URL: ')

print("[+] Connecting...")
try:
    if(video_url.endswith('&feature=related')):
        video_id = video_url.split('www.youtube.com/watch?v=')[1].split('&feature=related')[0]
    elif(video_url.endswith('&feature=dir')):
        video_id = video_url.split('www.youtube.com/watch?v=')[1].split('&feature=dir')[0]
    elif(video_url.endswith('&feature=fvst')):
        video_id = video_url.split('www.youtube.com/watch?v=')[1].split('&feature=fvst')[0]
    elif(video_url.endswith('&feature=channel_page')):
        video_id = video_url.split('www.youtube.com/watch?v=')[1].split('&feature=channel_page')[0]
    else:
        video_id = video_url.split('www.youtube.com/watch?v=')[1]
except:
    print("[-] Invalid URL.")
    exit(1)

print("[+] Parsing token...")
try:
    url = str(urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=' + video_id).read())
    token_value = url.split('video_id=' + video_id + '&token=')[1].split('&thumbnail_url')[0]

    download_url = "http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=" + video_id + "&t=" + token_value + "&fmt=18"
except:
    url = str(urllib.request.urlopen('www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + video_id))
    exit(1)

v_url = str(urllib.request.urlopen('http://' + video_url).read())
video_title = v_url.split('"rv.2.title": "')[1].split('", "rv.4.rating"')[0]
if '&quot;' in video_title:
    video_title = video_title.replace('&quot;', '"')
elif '&amp;' in video_title:
    video_title = video_title.replace('&amp;', '&')

print("[+] Downloading " + '"' + video_title + '"...')
try:
    print(download_url)
    file = open(video_title + '.mp4', 'wb')
    download = urllib.request.urlopen(download_url).read()
    print(download)
    for line in download:
        file.write(line)
        file.close()
except:
    print("[-] Error downloading. Quitting.")
    exit(1)

print("\n[+] Done. The video is saved to the current working directory(cwd).\n")
```

There’s an error message (thanks Wooble):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python31/MyLib/DrawingBoard/youtube_download-.py", line 52, in <module>
    download = urllib.request.urlopen(download_url).read()
  File "C:\Python31\lib\urllib\request.py", line 119, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\urllib\request.py", line 353, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\urllib\request.py", line 465, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\urllib\request.py", line 385, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\urllib\request.py", line 325, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\urllib\request.py", line 560, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\urllib\request.py", line 353, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\urllib\request.py", line 465, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\urllib\request.py", line 391, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\urllib\request.py", line 325, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\urllib\request.py", line 473, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Do you really think you can just grab onto a Youtube stream and save it as an mp4 file? Especially trying to `for line in download` over a binary stream looks amusing.

Comment: Tim, first this isnt my code, i just modified it for python3k. Second if i enter the url in my browser i can save it as a mp4. You seem smart, what do you suggest I do then?

Comment: The error seems on point here. That's the error the server is giving you. It's "Forbidden".

Comment: Thats true, but if i enter the url manually in my browser it works and i can download it.

Comment: Can you post the *entire* output of this program. I am interested in what the print statements output.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the entire output, the entire source code and error msges i received is there, could u clarify?

Comment: Here's a tutorial on how to do exactly this: http://willdrevo.com/downloading-youtube-and-soundcloud-audio-with-python-and-pandas/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The code on the original question relies on several assumptions about the content of YouTube pages and URLs (expressed in constructs such as "url.split('something=')[1]") which may not always be true. I tested it and it might depend even on which related videos show on the page. You might have tripped on any of those specificities.

Here's a cleaner version, which uses urllib to parse URLs and query strings, and which successfully downloads a video. I've removed some of the try/except which didn't do much but exit, for clarity. Incidentally, it deals with Unicode video titles by removing non-ASCII characters from the filename to which the video is saved. It also takes any numbers of YouTube URLs and downloads them all. Finally, it masks its user-agent as Chrome for Mac (which is what I currently use).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen, FancyURLopener
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs, unquote

class UndercoverURLopener(FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.9 Safari/533.2"

urllib.request._urlopener = UndercoverURLopener()

def youtube_download(video_url):
    video_id = parse_qs(urlparse(video_url).query)['v'][0]

    url_data = urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=' + video_id).read()
    url_info = parse_qs(unquote(url_data.decode('utf-8')))
    token_value = url_info['token'][0]

    download_url = "http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id={0}&t={1}&fmt=18".format(
        video_id, token_value)

    video_title = url_info['title'][0] if 'title' in url_info else ''
    # Unicode filenames are more trouble than they're worth
    filename = video_title.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii').replace("/", "-") + '.mp4'

    print("\t Downloading '{}' to '{}'...".format(video_title, filename))

    try:
        download = urlopen(download_url).read()
        f = open(filename, 'wb')
        f.write(download)
        f.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("\t Download failed! {}".format(str(e)))
        print("\t Skipping...")
    else:
        print("\t Done.")

def main():
    print("\n--------------------------")
    print (" YouTube Video Downloader")
    print ("--------------------------\n")

    try:
        video_urls = sys.argv[1:]
    except:
        video_urls = input('Enter (space-separated) video URLs: ')

    for u in video_urls:
        youtube_download(u)
    print("\n Done.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Just made a small edit to fix a spurious single-tick that showed up at the video title.

Comment: thanks for your effort, the code looks much cleaner now, i should have removed the try except statements myself. however it still results in an error when i attempt to download a video.

Comment: On the url_info line, if i'm not wrong theres an additional ')'

Comment: maybe youtube knows that its a program, if i modify the headers of the request i could mimic a human user.

Comment: True, there's an additional ')', left when I edited the answer. I'm removing it.

Do you still get the Forbidden error? Could be you're trying too often and youtube is blocking you. I downloaded several different videos with this code.

It could also be a specific video. Which one are you trying to download? For instance, I've downloaded http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEDP6xfAiVw several times with the above code, without further issues ("[+] Downloading 'Cycling in Amsterdam'..." -> "Cycling in Amsterdam.mp4"). Try downloading this one.

Comment: BTW, I didn't modify the headers at all, and it worked. If you've been trying too often, maybe they've blocked your IP, at least for a while.

Comment: Edited once more, to deal more elegantly with unicode video titles. I've also changed the code to use python3-style string formatting, instead of joining strings with "+"

Comment: I really appreciate the amt of effort you put into the script, i'm still receiving the same error, i noticed that your method for retrieving the video is roughly the same as the method in the script i posted.

Comment: I managed to get rid of the 403 i think by adding a host param as part of the header.

Comment: I haven't properly inspected Jake's script yet, but it looks nice (with bonus points for downloading from Vimeo as well). Still, I'm having fun with this downloader, so I've re-structured it to make it download an arbitrary number of videos.

It also masquerades as a web browser, which might help you with you Forbidden error (but I never get it, so I can't properly test it).

Comment: `youtube.com/get_video_info` no longer supported?

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to shamelessly plug [my script](http://github.com/JakeWharton/py-videodownloader) which automates checking for valid formats, automatically choosing the best quality format for a video, and works on both the [Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) and HTML5 variants of YouTube pages (as well as [Vimeo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimeo)).

If you wrote that script then please look at my source code for inspiration and feel free to steal some code. I challenge you to please write something better. Open source thrives on competition!

However, if you copied that script and are just trying to get it working, may I suggest you give my script a try and see if it fares better for you. You can access it both from the command line as a script or even as a module in another Python file.

Comment: Just wanted to see how the script i posted worked. Thanks for posting yours, i'm going to have a look.

Comment: Hey isit possible to pull a key:value pair from the http response header you receive from youtube? get_headers?

Comment: I entered the headers, no errors  this time but the file size is way too small to be the video, do i need to buffer the download? how do i do that? also you have a download_callback procedure? what does that do?

Comment: Also to add, using urllib, if the page i request is redirected, how do i get urllib to return the redirected address?

Comment: As you can see from http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen you can use `.info()` to retrieve header information from the return object. The `download_callback` function is only used for Vimeo to determine whether the file is an MP4 or MOV. I'm not sure how redirects work but there is a `HTTPRedirectHandler` class in `urllib2`

Answer (score 4):

You may also check [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) which is written in Python and check how it's written.

Comment: A decent tutorial for using `youtube-dl` here: http://willdrevo.com/downloading-youtube-and-soundcloud-audio-with-python-and-pandas/

Comment: 2015 the marked answer didn`t work for me, this did kudos

Comment: Is it being kept up-to-date with the (deliberate) changes YouTube makes (to break the downloaders)?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like YouTube guys have changed algorithms for accessing video files. Instead of "token" they now use "signature" variable, and "signature" seems to be dependent on either cookie-stored data or IP address of the client (in case of cookies-disabled browser like urllib in Python 2). Here's a hack I've come up with (URLs are IP address-locked):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
from urlparse import *
from urllib import *

def yt_url(video_url):
    video_id = parse_qs(urlparse(video_url).query)['v'][0]

    get_vars = parse_qs(unquote(urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id="+video_id).read()))

    url = get_vars["id"][0].split(",")[1].split("|")[1]

    elements = dict()
    elements["itag"] = get_vars["itag"][0]
    elements["sver"] = get_vars["sver"][0]
    elements["expire"] = get_vars["expire"][0]
    elements["signature"] = get_vars["signature"][0]
    elements["factor"] = get_vars["factor"][0]
    elements["id"] = get_vars["id"][0].split(",")[0]
    elements["key"] = get_vars["key"][0]
    elements["burst"] = get_vars["burst"][0]
    elements["sparams"] = get_vars["sparams"][0]
    elements["algorithm"] = get_vars["algorithm"][0]
    elements["ipbits"] = "8"

    for get_var in elements:
      url += "&" + get_var + "=" + elements[get_var]

    return (get_vars["title"][0], url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    (title, url) = yt_url("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tAr7tuakt0")
    print "Title: %s" % (title,)
    print "Video: %s" % (url,)
```

Comment: Re *"YouTube guys have changed algorithms for accessing video files"*: Yes, they ***deliberately*** do it on a regular basis in order to break the downloaders.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib2, urllib
import re
import os
import sys
import time

linkurl =raw_input('Enter URL:')
linkurl1 = urllib.urlopen(linkurl).read()
file1 = open("index.html", "w")
file1.write(linkurl1)
file1.close()
fname = 'index.html'

## Giving new matrix value to find
find = ("yt.playerConfig =", '"title":')

## File reading programme
with open(fname) as infile:
       for line_no, line in enumerate(infile, 1):
           lline = line.lower()
           if any(word.lower() in lline for word in find):
               y = line.rstrip()
fileurl = y
y1 = y.replace("%3A%2F%2F", "://")
y2 = y1.replace("%2F", "/")
y3 = y2.replace("%3F", "?")
y4 = y3.replace("%3D", "=")
y5 = y4.replace("%26", "&")
y6 = y5.replace("%252", "%2")
y7 = y6.replace("sig", "&signature")

# Display video resolution information
print ""
print "Video resolution: "
print "[46=1080(.webm)]--[37=1080(.mp4)]--[35=480(.flv)]--[36=180(.3gpp)]"
print "[45=720(.webm) ]--[22=720(.mp4) ]--[34=360(.flv)]--[17=144(.3gpp)]"
print "[44=480(.webm) ]--[18=360(.mp4) ]--[5=240(.flv) ]"
print "[43=360(.webm) ]"
print ""
# Programme to get all itag list file
itag = re.findall('itag=(\d+)', y)
print `"itag list= "` + `itag`
resol = raw_input("Type itag number: ")
# Programme to get filename file
fname = 'index.html'
find = (' <title>', '</title>')
with open(fname) as infile:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(infile, 1):
        lline = line.lower()
        if any(word.lower() in lline for word in find):
          y = line.rstrip()
fileurl1 = y.split(">")[-2]
filename2 = fileurl1.split('"')[-2]

if resol == '46':
   # Programme to get WebM file in 1080 HD
   y1080_webm = re.findall(r'itag=46(.*?)\u0026quality=hd1080', y7)
   url_1080_webm1 = re.findall(r'\\u0026url=(.*?)\\u0026type', `y1080_webm`)
   signature = re.findall(r'signature=(.*?)\\', `y1080_webm`)
   url_1080_webm2 = `url_1080_webm1`.split("\\")[0]
   url_1080_webm = url_1080_webm2.split("'")[1] + "&signature=" + `signature`.split("'")[1] + "&ptk=machinima"
   url = url_1080_webm
   #print url_1080_webm
   ext = ".webm"
elif resol == '37':
   # Programme to get MP4 file in 1080 HD
   y1080_mp4 = re.findall(r'itag=37(.*?)\u0026quality=hd1080', y7)
   url_1080_mp41 = re.findall(r'\\u0026url=(.*?)\\u0026type', `y1080_mp4`)
   signature = re.findall(r'signature=(.*?)\\', `y1080_mp4`)
   url_1080_mp42 = `url_1080_mp41`.split("\\")[0]
   url_1080_mp4 = url_1080_mp42.split("'")[1] + "&signature=" + `signature`.split("'")[1] + "&ptk=machinima"
   url = url_1080_mp4
   #print url_1080_mp4
   ext = ".mp4"
elif resol == '45':
   # Programme to get WebM file in 720 HD
   y720_webm = re.findall(r'itag=45(.*?)\u0026quality=hd720', y7)
   url_720_webm1 = re.findall(r'\\u0026url=(.*?)\\u0026type', `y720_webm`)
   signature = re.findall(r'signature=(.*?)\\', `y720_webm`)
   url_720_webm2 = `url_720_webm1`.split("\\")[0]
   url_720_webm = url_720_webm2.split("'")[1] + "&signature=" + `signature`.split("'")[1] + "&ptk=machinima"
   url = url_720_webm
   #print url_720_webm
   ext = ".webm"
elif resol == '22':
   # Programme to get MP4 file in 720 HD
   y720_mp4 = re.findall(r'itag=22(.*?)\u0026quality=hd720', y7)
   url_720_mp41 = re.findall(r'\\u0026url=(.*?)\\u0026type', `y720_mp4`)
   signature = re.findall(r'signature=(.*?)\\', `y720_mp4`)
   url_720_mp42 = `url_720_mp41`.split("\\")[0]
   url_720_mp4 = url_720_mp42.split("'")[1] + "&signature=" + `signature`.split("'")[1] + "&ptk=machinima"
   url = url_720_mp4
   #print url_720_mp4
   ext = ".mp4"
elif resol == '44':
   # Programme to get WebM file in 480 large
   y480_webm = re.findall(r'itag=44(.*?)\u0026quality=large', y7)
   url_480_webm1 = re.findall(r'\\u0026url=(.*?)\\u0026type', `y480_webm`)
   signature = re.findall(r'signature=(.*?)\\', `y480_webm`)
   url_480_webm2 = `url_480_webm1`.split("\\")[0]
   url_480_webm = url_480_webm2.split("'")[1] + "&signature=" + `signature`.split("'")[1] + "&ptk=machinima"
   url = url_480_webm
   #print url_480_webm
   ext = ".webm"
elif resol == '35':
   # Programme to get a FLV file in 480 large
   y480_flv = re.findall(r'itag=35(.*?)\u0026quality=large', y7)
   url_480_flv1 = re.findall(r'\\u0026url=(.*?)\\', `y480_flv`)
   signature = re.findall(r'signature=(.*?)\\', `y480_flv`)
   url_480_flv2 = `url_480_flv1`.split("\\")[0]
   url_480_flv = url_480_flv2.split("'")[1] + "&signature=" + `signature`.split("'")[1] + "&ptk=machinima"
   url = url_480_flv
   #print url_480_flv
   ext = ".flv"
elif resol == '43':
   # Programme to get WebM file in 360 medium
   y360_webm = re.findall(r'itag=43(.*?)\u0026quality=medium', y7)
   url_360_webm1 = re.findall(r'\\u0026url=(.*?)\\', `y360_webm`)
   signature = re.findall(r'signature=(.*?)\\', `y360_webm`)
   url_360_webm2 = `url_360_webm1`.split("\\")[0]
   url_360_webm = url_360_webm2.split("'")[1] + "&signature=" + `signature`.split("'")[1] + "&ptk=machinima"
   url = url_360_webm
   #print url_360_webm
   ext = ".webm"
elif resol == '34':
   # Programme to get FLV file in 360 medium
   y360_flv = re.findall(r'itag=34(.*?)\u0026quality=medium', y7)
   url_360_flv1 = re.findall(r'\\u0026url=(.*?)\\', `y360_flv`)
   signature = re.findall(r'signature=(.*?)\\', `y360_flv`)
   url_360_flv2 = `url_360_flv1`.split("\\")[0]
   url_360_flv = url_360_flv2.split("'")[1] + "&signature=" + `signature`.split("'")[1] + "&ptk=machinima"
   url = url_360_flv
   #print url_360_flv
   ext = ".flv"
elif resol == '18':
   # Programme to get MP4 file in 360 medium
   y360_mp4 = re.findall(r'itag=18(.*?)\u0026quality=medium', y7)
   url_360_mp41 = re.findall(r'\\u0026url=(.*?)\\', `y360_mp4`)
   signature = re.findall(r'signature=(.*?)\\', `y360_mp4`)
   url_360_mp42 = `url_360_mp41`.split("\\")[0]
   url_360_mp4 = url_360_mp42.split("'")[1] + "&signature=" + `signature`.split("'")[1] + "&ptk=machinima"
   url = url_360_mp4
   #print url_360_mp4
   ext = ".mp4"
elif resol == '5':
   # Programme to get FLV file in 240 small
   y240_flv = re.findall(r'itag=5(.*?)\u0026quality=small', y7)
   url_240_flv1 = re.findall(r'\\u0026url=(.*?)\\', `y240_flv`)
   signature = re.findall(r'signature=(.*?)\\', `y240_flv`)
   url_240_flv2 = `url_240_flv1`.split("\\")[0]
   url_240_flv = url_240_flv2.split("'")[1] + "&signature=" + `signature`.split("'")[1] + "&ptk=machinima"
   url = url_240_flv
   #print url_240_flv
   ext = ".flv"
elif resol == '36':
   # Programme to get 3gpp file in 180 small
   y180_3gpp = re.findall(r'itag=36(.*?)\u0026quality=small', y7)
   url_180_3gpp1 = re.findall(r'\\u0026url=(.*?)\\', `y180_3gpp`)
   signature = re.findall(r'signature=(.*?)\\', `y180_3gpp`)
   url_180_3gpp2 = `url_180_3gpp1`.split("\\")[0]
   url_180_3gpp = url_180_3gpp2.split("'")[1] + "&signature=" + `signature`.split("'")[1] + "&ptk=machinima"
   url = url_180_3gpp
   #print url_180_3gpp
   ext = ".3gpp"
elif resol == '17':
   # Programme to get 3gpp file in 144 small
   y144_3gpp = re.findall(r'itag=17(.*?)\u0026quality=small', y7)
   url_144_3gpp1 = re.findall(r'\\u0026url=(.*?)\\', `y144_3gpp`)
   signature = re.findall(r'signature=(.*?)\\', `y144_3gpp`)
   url_144_3gpp2 = `url_144_3gpp1`.split("\\")[0]
   url_144_3gpp = url_144_3gpp2.split("'")[1] + "&signature=" + `signature`.split("'")[1] + "&ptk=machinima"
   url = url_144_3gpp
   #print url_144_3gpp
   ext = ".3gpp"
#newindex = open("index1.txt", 'w')
#newindex.write(y7)
print url
filename = filename2 + ext
print filename
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'Range': "bytes=0-838860800"})

data = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print "connected to ""http://"+url.split("/")[2] + "/"
f = open(filename,'wb')
meta_data = data.info()
file_size = int(meta_data.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
print "filesize= " + `file_size/1048576` + " MB"
bytes_received = 0
chunk_size = 10240
while True:
    start_time = time.time()
    buffer = data.read(chunk_size)
    if not buffer:
            break

    bytes_received += len(buffer)
    f.write(buffer)
    Td = time.time() - start_time
    speed1 = round(len(buffer)/1024.0, 1)
    speed = round(speed1/Td, 1)
    speed_MB = round(speed/1024.0, 1)
    speed_GB = round(speed_MB/1024.0, 1)
    bytes_received_MB = round(bytes_received/1048576.0, 3)
    percent = bytes_received * 100. / file_size
    if speed < 1:
       speed_byte = round(len(buffer)/Td, 1)
       Tr = (file_size-bytes_received)/(60*speed_byte)
       status = r"[Downloaded=%.3f MB] [%3.2f%%]  [speed= %.1f B/s] [eta %1d min]             " % (bytes_received_MB, percent, speed_byte, Tr)
    elif speed < 1024:
       Tr = (file_size-bytes_received)/(60*1024*speed)
       status = r"[Downloaded=%.3f MB] [%3.2f%%]  [speed= %.1f KB/s] [eta %1d min]            " % (bytes_received_MB, percent, speed, Tr)
    elif speed < 1048576:
       Tr = (file_size-bytes_received)/(60*1024*1024*speed_MB)
       status = r"[Downloaded=%.3f MB] [%3.2f%%]  [speed= %.1f MB/s] [eta %1d min]            " % (bytes_received_MB, percent, speed_MB, Tr)
    else:
       Tr = (file_size-bytes_received)/(60*1024*1024*1024*speed_GB)
       status = r"[Downloaded=%.3f MB] [%3.2f%%]  [speed= %.1f GB/s] [eta %1d min]            " % (bytes_received_MB, percent, speed_GB, Tr)


    status = status + chr(8) * (len(status) + 1)
    print status,
```

Comment: This is my first python practical coding into youtube downloader. This is latest youtube video downloading according to youtube algorithm.

Comment: You should probably include this information into your answer so that it isn't just code (You can edit your answer  by clicking the edit button below it).

Comment: The indentation does not appear to be right near "`if not buffer:`"

Comment: There is ***a lot*** of redundant code here. There is something called [functional abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Subroutines). This linear code is a typical product of copy-paste reuse (the worst kind of reuse).

Comment: The [backtick notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673071/) for strings  (e.g., near *"y1080_mp4"*) was already [deprecated in 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673071/what-do-backticks-mean-to-the-python-interpreter-example-num/1673087#1673087). In Python 3 it doesn't work at all (`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`)