# Extract video from .swf using Python

Tags: python, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I've written code that generated the links to videos such as the one below.
Once obtained, I try to download it in this manner:

```
import urllib.request
import os

url = 'http://www.videodetective.net/flash/players/?customerid=300120&playerid=351&publishedid=319113&playlistid=0&videokbrate=750&sub=RTO&pversion=5.2%22%20width=%22670%22%20height=%22360%22'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
outpath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'video.mp4')
videofile = open(outpath , 'wb')
videofile.write(response)
videofile.close()
```

All I get is a 58kB file in that directory that can't be read. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678051/cant-download-youtube-video

Comment: @Sologoub: What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: Code I linked to can be used as a working start if he wants to figure it out... Although, the error seems to be more obvious as you pointed out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With your code, you aren't downloading the encoded video file here, but the flash application (in CWS-format) that is used to play the video. It is executed in the browser and dynamically loads and plays the video. You'd need to apply some reverse-engineering to figure out the actual video source. The following is my attempt at it:

**Decompressing the SWF file**

First, save the 58K file you mentioned on your hard disk under the name `test.swf` (or similiar).
You can then use the small Perl script [cws2fws](http://zefonseca.com/cws2fws/) for that:

```
perl cws2fws test.swf
```

This results in a new file named `test.fws.swf` in the same directory

**Searching for the configuration URL in the FWS file**

I used a simple

```
strings test.fws.swf | grep http
```

Which yields:

```
...
cookieOhttp://www.videodetective.net/flash/players/flashconfiguration.aspx?customerid=
...
```

Interesting. Let's try to put our known `customerid`, `playerid` and `publishedid` arguments to this URL:

```
http://www.videodetective.net/flash/players/flashconfiguration.aspx?customerid=300120&playerid=351&publishedid=319113
```

If we open that in a browser, we can see the player configuration XML, which in turn points us to

```
http://www.videodetective.net/flash/players/playlist.aspx?videokbrate=450&version=4.6&customerid=300120&fmt=3&publishedid=&sub=
```

Now if we open that, we can finally see the source URL:

```
http://cdn.videodetective.net/svideo/mp4/450/6993/293732.mp4?c=300120&r=450&s=293732&d=153&sub=&ref=&fmt=4&e=20111228220329&h=03e5d78201ff0d2f7df9a
```

Now we can download this h264 video file and we are finished.

**Automating the whole process in a Python script**

This is an entirely different task (left as an exercise to the reader).

Comment: Turns out that the perl script uses zlib, and its fairly straightforward. So is this one https://github.com/binjo/utils/blob/master/cws2fws.py

Comment: Okay, but actually I don't think you need to extract the file to automate the process of getting the configuration XML and all that stuff. This was just to get the initial information where it is located. Have fun.

Comment: When I use script convert cws to fws it tells me: `zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check`. Is it mean my swf file have some error or anything else? By the way the link of you script is broken.