# Python strings and integer concatenation

Tags: python, string, integer, concatenation

I want to create a string using an integer appended to it, in a *for* loop.  Like this:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
  string = "string" + i
```

But it returns an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

What's the best way to concatenate the string and integer?

Comment: Shouldn`t it be `range(1,10)`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is it the output you want to get? `string = "string10"`? `string = "string1string2string3string4string5string6string7string8string9string10"`? Ten different variables?

Comment: @stephan: +1, but it should be `range(1,11)` :)

Comment: @Tim: maybe even `range(11)` looking at the comment...

Comment: @michele Any chance you can change the accepted answer on this question? Backticks are deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: Sorry, I'm reading answers and I find it all so so weird, just do this and end with this:
for i in range(1,11):
  string += str(i)

Answer (score 315, accepted):

### NOTE:

The method used in this answer (backticks) is deprecated in later versions of Python 2, and removed in Python 3. Use the [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) function instead.

---

You can use:

```
string = 'string'
for i in range(11):
    string +=`i`
print string
```

It will print `string012345678910`.

To get `string0, string1 ..... string10` you can use this as [YOU suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847386/python-strings-and-integer-concatenation/2847394#2847394):

```
>>> string = "string"
>>> [string+`i` for i in range(11)]
```

---

## For Python 3

You can use:

```
string = 'string'
for i in range(11):
    string += str(i)
print string
```

It will print `string012345678910`.

To get `string0, string1 ..... string10`, you can use this as [YOU suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847386/python-strings-and-integer-concatenation/2847394#2847394):

```
>>> string = "string"
>>> [string+str(i) for i in range(11)]
```

Comment: if i input this: `47`, then why do i get this in my string:`u'47'`

Comment: This answer is outdated. Backticks are outdated and have been removed in Python 3. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673071/what-do-backticks-mean-to-the-python-interpreter-num) for more details. The other answers to this question are better solutions.

Comment: Backticks are the equivalent of the `repr()` function, not `str()`. For non-integer values, the `repr()` and `str()` results can differ significantly.

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @neoDev for which one?

Comment: in Python3, you can use f-strings like this:
string = f'{str}{number}'

Answer (score 278):

```
for i in range (1,10):
    string="string"+str(i)
```

To get `string0, string1 ..... string10`, you could do like

```
>>> ["string"+str(i) for i in range(11)]
['string0', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6', 'string7', 'string8', 'string9', 'string10']
```

Comment: It's still worth mentioning that backticks are equivalent to `repr()`, not `str()`.

Answer (score 40):

```
for i in range[1,10]: 
  string = "string" + str(i)
```

The `str(i)` function converts the integer into a string.

Answer (score 36):

```
string = 'string%d' % (i,)
```

Comment: you only need to use a list for formatting when you have more than one format specifier, otherwise, it's ugly :)

Comment: That's not a list, that's a tuple. And you also need it if the single item to be formatted is itself a tuple.

Answer (score 23):

```
for i in range(11):
    string = "string{0}".format(i)
```

You did (`range[1,10]`):

- a TypeError since brackets denote an index (`a[3]`) or a slice (`a[3:5]`) of a list,
- a SyntaxError since `[1,10]` is invalid, and
- a double off-by-one error since `range(1,10)` is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, and you seem to want `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

And `string = "string" + i` is a TypeError since you can't add an integer to a string (unlike JavaScript).

Look at the documentation for [Python's new string formatting method](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting). It is very powerful.

Comment: (Correction: If you do `range={(1,10): "foo"}`, then `range[1,10]` is in fact a syntactically valid expression.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a generator to do this!

```
def sequence_generator(limit):
    """ A generator to create strings of pattern -> string1,string2..stringN """
    inc  = 0
    while inc < limit:
        yield 'string' + str(inc)
        inc += 1

# To generate a generator. Notice I have used () instead of []
a_generator  =  (s for s in sequence_generator(10))

# To generate a list
a_list  =  [s for s in sequence_generator(10)]

# To generate a string
a_string =  '['+ ", ".join(s for s in sequence_generator(10)) + ']'
```

Answer (score 2):

If we want output like `'string0123456789'` then we can use the *map* function and *join* method of *string*.

```
>>> 'string' + "".join(map(str, xrange(10)))
'string0123456789'
```

If we want a *list* of string values then use the *list comprehension* method.

```
>>> ['string'+i for i in map(str,xrange(10))]
['string0', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6', 'string7', 'string8', 'string9']
```

**Note:**

Use *xrange()* for Python 2.x.

Use *range()* for Python 3.x.

Comment: Perhaps link (non-naked) to documentation for all those functions? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 2):

I did something else.

I wanted to replace a word, in lists of lists, that contained phrases.

I wanted to replace that string / word with a new word that will be a join between string and number, and that number / digit will indicate the position of the phrase / sublist / lists of lists.

That is, I replaced a string with a string and an incremental number that follow it.

```
myoldlist_1 = [[' myoldword'], [''], ['tttt myoldword'], ['jjjj ddmyoldwordd']]
    No_ofposition = []
    mynewlist_2 = []
    for i in xrange(0, 4, 1):
        mynewlist_2.append([x.replace('myoldword', "%s" % i + "_mynewword") for x in myoldlist_1[i]])
        if len(mynewlist_2[i]) > 0:
            No_ofposition.append(i)

mynewlist_2
No_ofposition
```

Answer (score -5):

Concatenation of a string and integer is simple:
just use

```
abhishek+str(2)
```

Comment: If it is so simple, perhaps explain (here or in the answer) why the previous seven answers weren't? E.g., did something change with later versions of Python?