# In Python 2.x, using backticks to get decimal string from int object is Horrible?

Tags: python, python-2.x, backticks

In Python 2.x, using backticks to get decimal string from int object is **Horrible**? 
Because backticks are `repr()`, not `str()`? I have noticed that when I answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847386/pythonstring-and-integer-concatenation/2847394#2847394) question.

In Python source, they have same function in Python source, [intobject.c](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/intobject.c)

```
(reprfunc)int_to_decimal_string,            /* tp_repr */
....
(reprfunc)int_to_decimal_string,            /* tp_str */
```

What do you think?

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I wouldn't say it's "horrible", but I feel it isn't right for at least four reasons:

1. `str(my_number)` states your intent more clearly than surrounding `my_number` by backticks. (See "Readability counts" in [the Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)).
2. The implementation of Python in C is just one possible implementation; there is Jython, IronPython, PyPy and so on, and unless there is an explicit statement in the Python specification somewhere that `repr()` and `str()` is the same for integer objects, I wouldn't to rely on that behaviour.
3. Backticks are gone in Python 3.x.
4. If your number happens to be so large that it cannot be represented by an `int`, Python promotes it automatically to a long integer, and for that, `repr()` and `str()` differs.

See this example:

```
>>> x = 1234567890
>>> y = x ** 3
>>> `y`
'1881676371789154860897069000L'
>>> str(y)
'1881676371789154860897069000'
```

Comment: To me another reason is that backticks probably come from the bash shell, so it probably doesn't make sense to people who don't know Unix.

Comment: 5. Constructs like repr(repr(x)) are confusing with the backquote syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Using backticks for anything is horrible.

You've got `str(i)`, you've got `'%d' % i`, you've got `.format(i)`; if you want the `repr` then say so directly with `repr()` or `%r` or whatever.

There was never a good reason to use backticks, they just made code less readable and much harder to parse. They are gone in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

2.X: Using backticks for anything is horrible. Use repr() or str() as required.

3.X: Backticks have vanished! Three cheers!!