# How to make a summation under a condition in Biopython

Tags: python, sum, conditional-statements, biopython

I have a FASTA file with three defined elements in the "description" line.

The first element, defined as `dato[0]`, is the one that has to carry out with the condition and the third element, defined as `dato[2]`, is the one that I want to sum.
The FASTA description line is like this:

```
PIN4 HOIAQKS02C4SWQ 1761
PIN1 HOIAQKS02D3JZ3 572
```

And I want to sum the values (`dato[2]`) that carry out the condition `dato[0] == PIN1` in one row and the condition `dato[0] == PIN4` in another.

I am using the following code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

secuencias=SeqIO.parse("/Users/imac/Desktop/Pruebas_UniFrac/otu1_alpin1+4.fasta", "fasta")

PIN_records=list(SeqIO.parse("/Users/imac/Desktop/Pruebas_UniFrac/otu1_alpin1+4.fasta", "fasta")

archivo1=open("/Users/imac/Desktop/Pruebas_UniFrac/pruebaalpin1+4_fin.fasta", "w")
archivo2=open("/Users/imac/Desktop/Pruebas_UniFrac/pruebaalpin1+4_seqsotus.fasta", "w")
archivo3=open("/Users/imac/Desktop/Pruebas_UniFrac/pruebaalpin1+4_sumas.fasta", "w")

x = 0
y = x+1
for linea in secuencias:
    dato = linea.description.split(" ")
    seqs = str(linea.seq)

    if dato[0] != "PIN1":
        if dato[0] != "PIN4":
            if dato[0] == "consensus":
               archivo1.write("hacia arriba OTU" + str(y) + "\n" + "x" + "\n" + "x" + "\n")
               archivo2.write(">" + "OTU" + str(y) + "\n" + seqs + "\n")
               archivo3.write("fin del OTU" + "\n")
               y = y+1
        else:
         archivo1.write(str(dato[0]) + "," + str(dato[2]) + "\n")
         #num = int(dato[2])
         #archivo3.write("PIN4=" + str(sum(dato[2])) + "\n")
         #archivo3.write("PIN4=%d\n" % sum(dato[2]))
         archivo3.write("PIN4={}\n".format(sum(dato[2])))
    else:
     archivo1.write(str(dato[0]) + "," + str(dato[2]) + "\n")
     #num = int(dato[2])
     #archivo3.write("PIN1=" + str(sum(dato[2])) + "\n")
     #archivo3.write("PIN1=%d\n" % sum(dato[2]))
     archivo3.write("PIN1={}\n".format(sum(dato[2])))

archivo1.close()
archivo2.close()
archivo3.close()
```

And when I do that, I get this error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

### How can I do that?

After following posterior comments, I have introduced changes in my code, but I can't get it working properly and I do not know how to fix it.

With this code, I get the following error:

```
File "./lectura_msaout_pruebaalpin1+4_final.py", line 16
    archivo1=open("/Users/imac/Desktop/Pruebas_UniFrac/pruebaalpin1+4_fin.fasta", "w")
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Did you try [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+unsupported+operand+type(s)+for+%2B%3A+'int'+and+'str') for your error message?

Comment: I did, but the solutions I found wasn't uitable for my problem, I think.

Comment: Some future advice: Please be more explicit about problems than "it doesn't work." It's hard to divine exactly what your issue is. Also, you should make an effort to [code in English](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/the-ugly-american-programmer.html). Spanish has a lot of cognates with English, but you're losing a lot of your potential audience when you code in another language (also, it's confusing to see English-based syntax with Spanish varnames).

Comment: When I say "It still doesn't work" I meant I still have the same problem as before: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str". Thanks a lot for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two main issues.

1. You're trying to call `sum()` on string data.
2. You're trying to format a numeric value as a string.

### Fixing summation

You want to sum an iterable of numeric values, as summing is undefined for string values. You can convert string values to an integer by calling `int()` on each value (use the `map()` function to do this).

#### Example:

```
>>> sum(["1", "2", "3"])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
>>> sum([1, 2, 3])
6
map(int, ["1", "2", "3"])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> sum(map(int, ["1", "2", "3"]))
6
```

#### Application to your code

Do you really want to sum the single digits of `dato[2]`? It'd look like this:

```
>>> dato = ['PIN4', 'HOIAQKS02C4SWQ', '1761']
>>> sum(map(int, dato[2]))  # 1 + 7 + 6 + 1
15
```

### Fixing the string formatting

You can't append an integer to a string (see [Python String and Integer concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847386/string-and-integer-concatenation)).

The solution is to either convert the integer to a string before concatenating, or to format the integer within a string. In your case, the solutions look like this:

1. Convert to string:

   ```
   archivo3.write("PIN1=" + str(dato_2_sum) + "\n")
   ```
2. Use string formatting:

   ```
   archivo3.write("PIN1=%d\n" % dato_2_sum)
   ```
3. Use newstyle formatting:

   ```
   archivo3.write("PIN1={}\n".format(dato_2_sum)
   ```

Comment: I still have the same problem, with any of the three options. I will copy the complete code in an answer.

Comment: I have edited the post with the whole code I am using. It still doesn't work, even after the three suggestions to convert the integrer to a string or format the integrer within a string.

Comment: I really don't want to sum the single digits of dato [2], but to sum all the dato[2] values from different fasta parts (I mean, from different data introduced by '>') if they carry out one condition, as it could be: >"PIN4" "HOIAQKS02C4SWQ" "1761"
>"PIN4" "HOIAQKS02D3JZ3" "572"------> They both carry out the condition for "dato[0]==PIN4", so we can sum "dato[2]" from both===> "1761"+"572"="2333". Thanks a lot, one more time

Comment: Iterate over all sequences, building a list of records (say, `PIN_records`) that satisfies your requirement, then sum index 2 for each record.

Comment: As you can see, I am very new at python, and I do not know how to do that. I have tried to write the list in many parts and I did not get anything that works properly. I got different errors, since syntax errors to unexpected indents. I am going to edit my question with the new text to see if you can see where I am making mistakes. Thanks a lot, I am quite lost with this and if you could help me working it out it could save a lot of time in my work. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have fixed up my problem by creating counters outside the 'for' cycle and creating a sum but without the 'sum' command and by changing between 'str' and 'int'. My 'almost finished' complete code is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


from Bio import SeqIO



sequences=SeqIO.parse("/Users/imac/Desktop/Pruebas_UniFrac/otu1_alpin1+4.fasta", "fasta")





file1=open("/Users/imac/Desktop/Pruebas_UniFrac/pruebaalpin1+4_fin.fasta", "w")
file2=open("/Users/imac/Desktop/Pruebas_UniFrac/pruebaalpin1+4_seqsotus.fasta", "w")
file3=open("/Users/imac/Desktop/Pruebas_UniFrac/pruebaalpin1+4_sumas.fasta", "w")


numTotalPin1=0
numTotalPin4=0



x=0
y=x+1

for line in sequences:


    data=line.description.split(" ")



    seqs=str(line.seq)


    if data[0]!="PIN1":
        if data[0]!="PIN4":
            if data[0]=="consensus":
               file1.write("upstream OTU" + str(y) + "\n" + "x" + "\n" + "x" + "\n")
               file2.write(">" + "OTU" + str(y) +"\n" + seqs + "\n")
               file3.write("OTU"+ str(y) + "\n")
               file3.write("PIN1=" + str(numTotalPin1) + "\n")
               file3.write("PIN4=" + str(numTotalPin4) + "\n")
               file3.write("end of OTU"+ str(y) + "\n")
               y=y+1
               numTotalPin1=0
               numTotalPin4=0
        else:
         file1.write(str(data[0]) + "," + str(data[2]) + "\n")
         num=int(data[2])
         numTotalPin4=numTotalPin4 + int(data[2])


    else:
     file1.write(str(data[0]) + "," + str(data[2]) + "\n")
     num=int(data[2])
     numTotalPin1=numTotalPin1 + int(data[2])



file1.close()
file2.close()
file3.close()
```

I hope that someone can find this code helpful.
Thanks for your help.