# Python..adding int to a variable

Tags: python

I am newbie with Python formatting.I have assigned an integer to a variable k as below:

```
k = 1
 tel = tel + [(%d + 1) % k]
print tel
```

I want to concatenate the string tel with the sum of `%d +1`

The above  code does not work as I am sure there is something wrong in the syntax. How do I write the correct form

Thanks!

Comment: What is "%d" supposed to be?

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847386/python-string-and-integer-concatenation

Comment: i still dont know why  u using %d ??

Comment: I think you what you want to do is `tel = tel + str(k+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you want is  `str()` function in python.which coerces data into a string

```
k = 1
 tel = tel + str(k+1)
print tel
```

Answer (score 0):

If `tel` is a string :

```
k = 1
tel = "tel%i1" % k
# or 
# tel = "tel" + str(k) +"1"
print tel
tel11
```

If it's a variable :

```
tel = "foo"
k = 1
tel = "%s%i1" %(tel, k)
# or
# tel = tel + str(k) + "1"
print tel
foo11
```

If you want to perform addition before concatenating :

```
k = 1
tel = "tel%i" %(k+1)
# or
# tel = "tel" + str(k+1)
print tel
tel2
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

to concatenate string with integer, you should convert integer into string (str()).

print ’hello’ + str(1) etc...

hope this w