# Changing title of image to display many images simultaneously using open cv and python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

Hi I am using open cv 2 library with python ver 2.7.6

I have written the code which basically takes a image as input

but the output shows only 1 window ... not n windows.

Can any one please tell how i can display all the split images in multiple windows simultaneously.

The code is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


def dr(img,direction,n):
     roi=[0] * 69 
     r,cv,c = img.shape
     print h,w,c

    return(roi)

 if __name__ == "__main__":

        img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
        img_roi=dr(img,0,65)
        cv2.waitKey(025)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: just change the name of the window, something like "title1", "title2", etc...

Comment: Ya how do i do it automatically  in a loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847386/python-string-and-integer-concatenation

Comment: Can u please give me the syntax.. its really difficult for me to understand the above post

Comment: Don't know python very well, but should be something like: `cv2.imshow('title' + str(i), roi[i])  `

Comment: I cannot test it. What's the error?

Comment: SOLVED
Replaced 
 cv2.imshow('title',roi[i])
by
 cv2.imshow('image %d' % (i,), roi[i])

Thank U Miki ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to change the window name for each different window. So I replaced

```
cv2.imshow('title',roi[i])
```

with

```
cv2.imshow('image %d' % (i,), roi[i])
```