# Creating a new Directory in Python 2.7

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program to spam new folders, but I cannot get it to work, I keep getting

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

but I am converting the string amount into an integer already

```
import os
def folderSpam():
    amount = raw_input("Please insert how many folders you want to create: ")
    amount = int(amount)
    path = raw_input("Please insert the directory to create the folders in: ")
    msg = raw_input("Please insert the spam name of the folders")
    for i in range(0, amount):
        amount0 = 0
        if amount0 == amount:
            exit()
        else:
            amount0 = amount0 + 1
            os.chdir(path)
            os.mkdir(msg + amount0)
            print "All folders have been created"
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: `msg + amount0` doesn't work. Try this instead:  `msg + str(amount0)`

Answer (score 1):

Use str(amount0) to do string and int concatenation.

Please check [Python String and Integer concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847386/python-string-and-integer-concatenation) for more details

```
import os
    def folderSpam():
        amount = raw_input("Please insert how many folders you want to create: ")
        amount = int(amount)
        path = raw_input("Please insert the directory to create the folders in: ")
        msg = raw_input("Please insert the spam name of the folders")
        for i in range(0, amount):
            amount0 = 0
            if amount0 == amount:
                exit()
            else:
                amount0 = amount0 + 1
                os.chdir(path)
                os.mkdir(msg + str(amount0))
                print "All folders have been created"
```