# Python: repr vs backquote

Tags: python, python-2.x

In python, is there a difference between `repr` and the backquote `` ` `` (left of 1)?

For demonstration:

```
class A(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'repr A'
    def __str__(self):
        return 'str A'


>>> a = A()

>>> repr(a)
#'repr A'

>>> `a`
#'repr A'

>>> str(a)
#'str A'
```

Do the backquotes just call `repr`? Is it simply for convenience? Is there any significant speed difference?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673071/what-do-backticks-mean-to-the-python-interpreter-num ?

Comment: Why would you worry about a speed difference?

Comment: @NedBatchelder, mostly for curiosity.

Comment: @TorelTwiddler: "mostly for curiosity" doesn't make a poor question any better.  You have `timeit` to satisfy your curiosity regarding speed.  You have the Python change notes to satisfy your curiosity on deprecated syntax.

Comment: @S.Lott: The first four items of a google search of `python backquotes` returns 2 items about backquotes in a shell, one about a depreciation warning that is hard to follow, and then _this_ question. I never thought to look for "reverse quotes" in the documentation because I've never heard them called that before (nor "backticks" for the duplicate question). I had no idea they were deprecated. How else should I go about finding information on a device that is rarely used and has multiple names?

Comment: @TorelTwiddler: Google is an interesting approach.  I didn't suggest it because it's difficult -- as you pointed out.  I suggested something that's NOT Google, because it's easier.  Perhaps you could compare the actual Python documentation and see if it's better than Google results?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

They're an alias for `repr`. They have the exact same effect.

However, they're deprecated and have been removed in Python 3. Don't use them; use `repr`.

Answer (score 9):

According to [python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) covering repr:

> This is the same value yielded by conversions (reverse quotes).

It should be noted that the backtick method is considered something of an abomination by the language designers at the moment, and [it was removed in python 3](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax).