# Python 2.X adding single quotes around a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently to add single quotes around a string, the best solution I came up with was to make a small wrapper function.

```
def foo(s1):
    return "'" + s1 + "'"
```

Is there an easier more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: What is the context (reasons/why) for doing this?  What if your string contain quotes?  Anyway try `s1.__repr__()` with various strings and see if this behavior suit your required usage.

Comment: @metatoaster I basically need to concatenate many strings `+`, some that need the single quotes and some that don't, in an effort to conserve line space I came up with the above solution

Comment: What if you got a string that matches your single quotes criteria but also has a single quote (such as `that's`), using your method would result in `'that's'`.  Is this intended/permissible for your system?  Also, it's recommended to use `str.join` over a list of strings rather than using `+` to add individual string fragments together, for performance reasons.

Comment: @metatoaster `that's` is not allowed, not worried about performance, and its expanding multiple lines so i'm currently using triple quotes `"""` with the `+`, `str.join` is a good idea

Comment: Wait, how does multiple lines come into play in this?  Are you reusing the output as python code?

Comment: @metatoaster just context and yes i'm reusing the output from the above `foo` function

Comment: Then just use `__repr__()`.

Answer (score 16):

Here's another (perhaps more pythonic) option, using [format strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
def foo(s1):
    return "'{}'".format(s1)
```

Answer (score 15):

What about:

```
def foo(s1):
    return "'%s'" % s1
```

Comment: This syntax for format strings has been deprecated, in favor of using the `format()` method as shown in my answer

Answer (score 13):

Just wanted to highlight what @metatoaster said in the comment above, as I missed it at first.

Using repr(string) will add single quotes, then double quotes outside of that, then single quotes outside of that with escaped inner single quotes, then onto other escaping.

Using repr(), as a built-in, is more direct, unless there are other conflicts..

```
s = 'strOrVar'
print s, repr(s), repr(repr(s)), ' ', repr(repr(repr(s))), repr(repr(repr(repr(s))))

# prints: strOrVar 'strOrVar' "'strOrVar'"   '"\'strOrVar\'"' '\'"\\\'strOrVar\\\'"\''
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) state its basically state repr(), i.e. representation, is the reverse of eval():

> "For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval(),.."

Backquotes would be shorter, but are [removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490261/python-repr-vs-backquote) in Python 3+.
Interestingly, StackOverflow uses backquotes to specify code spans, instead of highlighting a code block and clicking the code button - it has some interesting behavior though.

Answer (score 2):

This works on Python 3.5+

```
def foo2(char):
    return("'{}'".format(char))
```