# Adding a single quote around a string from a yaml file python

Tags: python

I want to print a string enclosed between two single quotes.  I've looked at this [question][1] and I've tried to use escape character ', but nothing:

```
def quote(string):
    return "'%s'" % string
```

I tried this function:

```
old = 'testing String'
test_string = quote(old)
```

But when I print `test_string` I have this output:

```
'''testing String'''
```

Why do I get three single quotes?
Thanks.

EDIT  :
Stand alone answers may work, but I'm trying to edit a value inside a yaml file :
that's my code :

```
import yaml
import sys
import random
import string



def quote(string):
    return "'{}'" .format(string)



email = sys.argv[1]
dominio = email.split("@")
nome = (dominio[0].split("."))[0].capitalize()
cognome = (dominio[0].split("."))[1].capitalize()
password = random = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in xrange(8)])
x={}
with open('/home/francesco/Musica/prova.yaml', 'r') as my_file:
    x = yaml.load(my_file)
x['accounts']['addresses']['username'] = quote(email)
x['accounts']['addresses']['address'] = email
x['accounts']['email'] = email
x['accounts']['firstname'] = nome
x['accounts']['lastname'] = cognome
x['accounts']['password1'] = password
x['accounts']['password2'] = password
x['accounts']['username'] = email
with open('output.yaml', 'w') as new_file:
    yaml.dump(x, new_file,default_flow_style=False)
```

`quote(email)` return email content enclosed on three single quote, i don't know why
[1]: [Python 2.X adding single quotes around a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952543/python-2-x-adding-single-quotes-around-a-string)

Comment: Are you sure this is not actually `"'testing String'"`  (double quotes around the single quotes, as the `repr` would display)?

Comment: no there is three single quote.
I don't know how can i remove that and using only a single quote around that string

Comment: Code works for me. Try: `print(test_string)` vs just `test_string`

Comment: ok i've tested single and it works, maybe it because i'm using it on a dictionary value?

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and it actually works correctly on my PC.

But since the % syntax has been deprecated, I'll recommend you use the new .format().

Here's a ref for you : https://pyformat.info/

and the code for your answer will be :

```
def quote(string):
    return "'{}'" .format(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

`return repr(string)`

Comment: This should be a comment!

Comment: always same result

Answer (score 0):

You \' to insert a single quote. And calling repr() will represent the data in the format it is. instead use str()