# Why does backtick string conversion work sporadically in my Django application?

Tags: python, django

I am writing a Django application, and I often use the Python backtick operator to convert integers to strings.

Recently, I found that a form in my application was broken. After rewriting several backticks into str(), the application was fixed.

Specifically, where course is an object, I changed

``course.id `\`

into `str(course.id)` to fix the application.

When does the backtick operator work, and when does it not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do backticks mean to the python interpreter: `num`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673071/what-do-backticks-mean-to-the-python-interpreter-num)

Comment: They were [already deprecated in 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673071/what-do-backticks-mean-to-the-python-interpreter-example-num/1673087#1673087).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backticks are an alias for [`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr), not for [`str()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str).  There are types where `repr()` and `str()` return the same value, hence the confusion.

For user output, you should always use `str()`.  Backticks probably shouldn't be used at all -- they have been removed in Python 3.x since they were considered a misfeature.

Comment: +1 They (backticks) come in handy when code golfing but that's indeed the only place where you can get away with it's usage. It's very rare to see them elsewhere.

Comment: And in django, you should probably use unicode() rather than str()