# Python accent graves bad practice?

Tags: python, repr

I have recently come to understand that we can use the following as a shorthand for `repr(x)` in Python:

```
`x`
```

However, I have rarely seen this in practice. Is it considered to be bad practice or *unpythonic*? Or are there any other reasons for which it is rarely used?

Comment: It was removed from Py3k. For me is enough reason not to use it.

Comment: And they were deprecated because they are hard to read and verging on implicit when `repr` is so much more clear. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673071/what-do-backticks-mean-to-the-python-interpreter-num

Comment: It was totally worth it to save 4 characters when we were paying > $1/GB for harddrive space, now harddrives got cheaper. Noone cares much if you waste 0.0000004 cents

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think many people would argue that it's Pythonic especially since it's been removed from Python3

Prior to that, I would never use it in real code. The problem being that quite a few developers didn't know what it was for, and it's not very easy to search for.

There has also been a move in Python3 to have `.__next__()` method instead of `.next()` for iterators, which strengthens the idea that `repr(x)` calls `x.__repr__()` etc.