# Python join date and filename

Tags: python, linux

I am learning python and i am trying to write a stupid code and got stuck here, I am need backupfile name like `full-backup-ucs-2013-02-12`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from time import strftime

DATE=`strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`
backupfile = "full-backup-ucs-" + DATE

print backupfile
```

When i run i got following output, did you see it print two single quote `' '` in date, I want to remove them. I am sure there is elegant way to do that please suggest:

```
[spatel@tux work]$ ./backup.py
full-backup-ucs-'2013-02-12'
```

Comment: As a side note, I'm +1 to this since I would have sworn that backtics would produce a SyntaxError before this question :)

Comment: Be ready! I have started learning python so more questions are on my way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `datetime` module to get this information.

```
import datetime
DATE = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

As I'm sure you've noticed, [backtic substitution doesn't work in python as it does in the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673071/what-do-backticks-mean-to-the-python-interpreter-num).  It implicitly calls `repr` (in python2.x) which is where your additional quotes are coming from.

**EDIT** -- Apparently you could just use remove the backtics and your code should more or less work as [`time.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) uses the current localtime if you omit the second argument.

Comment: Cool! I don't get your second solution about time.strftime

Comment: Awesome! i get it... it works without backtics :)  DATE=strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

Answer (score 1):

You can just put text in the format string right away:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from time import strftime

print strftime("full-backup-ucs-%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it without the backticks:

```
import time
print time.strftime("full-backup-ucs-%Y-%m-%d")
```