# Passing PHP vars inside SQL statement to SQLite3 with exec

Tags: php, sqlite, exec

I'm trying to get variables into a SQL statement that is executed via `exec` on a SQLite DB.

The example given [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_php.htm) uses EOF to put the SQL in but from what I understand till now is that it's not possible to put php vars inside such tags?

So I'm trying to get them over by:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  `certsIssued` (clientID, userName, dateIssued, revocationDate) VALUES ('".$clientID."','".$userName."', '".$dateIssued."', '".$dateRevocation."')";
$ret = $db->exec($sql); // with no luck 500 error
```

and

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  `certsIssued` (clientID, userName, dateIssued, revocationDate) VALUES ('\".$clientID.\"','\".$userName.\"', '\".$dateIssued.\"', '\".$dateRevocation.\"')";
$ret = $db->exec($sql); // with no luck 500 error
```

and

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  `certsIssued` (clientID, userName, dateIssued, revocationDate) VALUES ({$clientID},{$userName}, {$dateIssued}, {$dateRevocation})";
$ret = $db->exec($sql); // with no luck 500 error
```

Can someone please explain to me how to get this right?

***got it working making a new page by an examplepage that i left mostly intact besides my querystring and vars. I can insert and query the results. Must be something wrong in the surrounding code of my project that messes things up***

```
<?php
$number = 1;
$period = 'day';
$userName = 'meandmyself';
$clientID = uniqid();
$dateIssued = new \DateTime("now");
$dateIssued = $dateIssued->format('Y/m/d/h/i/s');
$dateRevocation = new \DateTime("+".$number." ".$period);
$dateRevocation = $dateRevocation->format('Y/m/d/h/i/s');

class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
  function __construct()
  {
     $this->open('db/test.db');
  }
}
$db = new MyDB();
if(!$db){
  echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else {
  echo "Opened database successfully\n";
}

 $sql = "INSERT INTO  `certsIssued` (clientID, userName, dateIssued, revocationDate) VALUES ('".$clientID."','".$userName."', '".$dateIssued."', '".$dateRevocation."')";
 $ret = $db->exec($sql);
 if(!$ret){
  echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
 } else {
  echo "Records created successfully\n";
 }
  $db->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: What's with the quotes around `certsIssued`?

Comment: What is `$db->lastErrorMsg`?

Comment: Backticks around table names are MySQL syntax.

Comment: @Barmar  --I do it always this way database.tablname.-- Forget it, i read the comment wrong.

Comment: And according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141090/sqlite-use-backticks-or-double-quotes-with-python SQLite also allows backticks for MySQL compatibility.

Comment: To the question: first tryout is ok (no syntax error), 2,3 are wrong. In 2 escaping makes no sense there, because you want to parse the $variable and the backslashs prevents that. In the 3 you have to add single quotes to get it work, like `'{$clientID}'`

Comment: But what you really should do is `escape` the values before using in a query. And `500 Error` means 500 Internal Server Error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961104/500-internal-server-error-using-php-and-sqlite, so the query is ok, your Database is not working right.

Comment: I updated the question with a sample i put together to see that what @JustOnUnderMillions said about the first statement being the right one without syntaxes errors. It had to be something in the surrounding code of my project that is messing things up. I was defining the class whithin a function i use? Perhaps it;s that? But that would be another question.?

Comment: Ahum.... db/test.db should be ../db/test.db . I'm so sorry for the waste of your time! :-)

Comment: **Do not use string manipulation on queries**, use query parameters (not escaping).