# sqlite3 - incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 42 supplied

Tags: python

```
def writeRowsToDB():
  data = getListsData()
  placeholders = getPlaceHolders()
  columns = columnsTuple()
  for i in range(len(data)):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO langs "+ columns + "VALUES " + placeholders, (rowsTuple(i)))
  conn.commit()
```

So I'm trying to insert some rows into a table named langs. Variables: data is a list of lists, where each list is a row taken from a json blob. placeholders is a string of 42 "?" seperated by commas, it initially was a tuple of 42 "?" but i couldnt concatenate tuples so had to convert to string. Columns is another tuple converted into a string that are my column names already located in the table. Finally rowsTuple(x) is a function that takes one parameter and returns a list converted into tuple form. This tuple is my rows contents, there are 42 elements in this tuple each time I loop through range(len(data)). New-ish to coding so if I left out any needed information please let me know. Thank you.

EDIT* I added a function to build my sql string to see what it was printing out, everything looks in order to me, 42 place holders for my 42 values to place in my 42 columns.

```
    def query():
  placeholders = getPlaceHolders()
  columns = columnsTuple()
  sql = "INSERT INTO langs "+ columns + "VALUES " + placeholders
  print ('insert into string:\n')
  print (sql + '\n')
  print ('values\n')
  print (rowsTuple(0))
```

Console:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y929x.jpg

Comment: _Always_ specify the target columns for an insert.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thought I did that with "+ columns"

Comment: Try printing your SQL statement from Python; my guess is that you'll immediately see the problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not sure what you mean by that, when i ran writeRowsToDb() only thing being printed is the error I posted.

Comment: Build the SQL string and then print it to the console.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not too familiar with sql query string formatting but i'll look into it thanks

Comment: I think you are missing my point.  Your current efforts to generate an insert SQL string are not producing what you expect.  The obvious first thing to check is to look at what Python is in fact generating.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok, I made an edit in the original post showing what python is generating for my insert sql string. It looks like it should be syntactically correct so I am still confused about the binding error.

Comment: Well for one thing, all of your column names are in single quotes.  That's incorrect.

Comment: @insult: Furthermore, **all** bindings in single quotes `'?'` an therefore you get the error: ***`The current statement uses 0`***

Comment: @stovfl Ah i see now, thank you guys

Comment: @stovfl https://imgur.com/a/t5m0dBP so I made the adjustments whats this syntax error about?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen cant @ multiple users in one post ^^

Comment: @insult Read [Use backticks (\`) or double quotes (`"`) with python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25141338/7414759)