# python-How to reverse an negative integer or non-integer

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am learning python and I meet some troubles.

I want to write the script to reverse a negative integer " -1234 to 4321- " and non-integer " 1.234 to 432.1". please help me. 
P.S. cannot use "str()" function

I just only can write the script to reverse positive integer 1234 to 4321

```
def reverse_int(n):

    x = 0
    while n > 0:
        x *= 10
        x += n % 10
        n /= 10
    return x
print reverse_int(1234)
```

Comment: `4321-` in not a valid number! do you want to convert it to string?

Comment: 4321- is not a valid integer.  How do you plan on representing that as anything other than a string?

Comment: He just said he mustn't use the function `str()`, not that he cannot use strings. Hence, `def reverse_int(n): return '{}'.format(n)[::-1]` should work.

Comment: I don't understant your script. Could you post details of your solution?

Comment: is this homework ? since you cannot use the `str` function

Comment: Hyperboreus' script is just using string substitution using the `format` function, and then reversing the string by using slice notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using your code, but just concatenate a `-` when `n` is negative?

**rev_int.py:**

```
def reverse_int(m):
    x = 0
    n = m
    if m < 0 :
      n *= -1
    while n > 0 :
        x *= 10
        x += n % 10
        n /= 10
    if m < 0:
      #concatenate a - sign at the end
      return `x` + "-"
    return x

print reverse_int(1234)
print reverse_int(-1234)
```

This produces:

```
$ python rev_int.py
4321
4321-
```

Comment: How are you concatenating a string with an integer at `return \`x\` + "-"`?

Comment: I can't get this code to work properly for negative numbers, either in Skulpt or in my Python 3 (changing `print` to a function and `/=` to `//=`).

Comment: How is that any different from using `str()`? You might as well just do `return \`m\`[::-1]`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The question is for reversing `integers`, the back ticks convert an integer to string; see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847386/python-string-and-integer-concatenation) so the concatenation works. This code would work in Python 2.x, would need change for Python3. Also the question asks NOT to use `str()`

Comment: 1. I don't think using the syntactic equivalent of `repr()` matches the spirit of the question any better than using `str()`, 2. the question clearly mentions non-integers in both the title and the body, giving an example of `1.234`, and 3. if you're going to use `repr()`/`\`\``, you might as well replace the whole body of the function with `return repr(m)[::-1]`, and then it'll work on Python 2 and 3, for both `int`s and `float`s.

Comment: backticks are deprecated, should not be used. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1673087/1860929

Answer (score 3):

```
def reve(x):
    x=str(x)
    if x[0]=='-':
        a=x[::-1]
        return f"{x[0]}{a[:-1]}"
    else:
        return x[::-1]

print(reve("abc"))
print(reve(123))
print(reve(-123))
```

#output
cba
321
-321

Comment: While this code might answer the OP's question, you could make your answer much better by appending an explanation on how your code solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Using SLICING EASILY DONE IT

```
def uuu(num):
if num >= 0: 
    return int(str(num)[::-1])
else:
    return int('-{val}'.format(val = str(num)[1:][::-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code runs fine on Python-3 and handles positive and negative integer case. Below code takes **STDIN** and prints the output on **STDOUT**.

> Note: below code handles only the integer case and doesn't handles the
> non-integer case.

```
def reverseNumber(number):
        x = 0
        #Taking absolute of number for reversion logic
        n = abs(number)
        rev = 0
        #Below logic is to reverse the integer
        while(n > 0):
            a = n % 10
            rev = rev * 10 + a
            n = n // 10
        #Below case handles negative integer case
        if(number < 0):
            return (str(rev) + "-")
        return (rev)
#Takes STDIN input from the user
number=int(input())
#Calls the reverseNumber function and prints the output to STDOUT
print(reverseNumber(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using str convert method.

```
num = 123
print(str(num)[::-1])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use this as a guide and make it work for floating point values as well:

```
import math

def reverse_int(n):
    if abs(n) < 10:
        v = chr(abs(n) + ord('0'))
        if n < 0: v += '-'
        return v
    else:
        x = abs(n) % 10
        if n < 0: return chr(x + ord('0')) + reverse_int(math.ceil(n / 10))
        else: return chr(x + ord('0')) + reverse_int(math.floor(n / 10))

print reverse_int(1234)
```

Comment: output is  40 no matter 1234 or -1234 @@

Answer (score -3):

Why not just do the following?:

```
def reverse(num):
    revNum = ''
    for i in `num`:
        revNum = i + revNum
    return revNum

print reverse(1.12345)
print reverse(-12345)
```

These would print 54321.1 and 54321-.

Comment: If you wanted simple, you could've copied my `return \`m\`[::-1]` comment exactly instead of adding a loop. And, of course, I don't think `repr()` (what `\`\`` does in Python 2 - `repr()` would be better anyway because it works in 2 and 3) is any better than `str()`.

Comment: As written, your script produces 1000000000054321.1 for 1.12345.