# Python: retrying after exception is leaving the line that caused exception

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python. I'm using BeautifulSoup - python module. I have to find and get text of any  id  like `MathJax-Element-1, MathJax-Element-2, MathJax-Element-3, MathJax-Element-4,….`  so on if it exists.

my code is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
attempts = 0
a=-1

while attempts < 100:
    try:
        a+=1
        math="MathJax-Element-"
        math +=`a`
        soup=(soup.find(id=math))
        print(soup.get_text())
        attempts = 0
    except AttributeError:
        attempts +=1
```

but after an attribute error the code fails. For example if there is no id  MathJax-Element-2, then I am not getting text of any id following that,  like  MathJax-Element-3 and MathJax-Element-4

trying after exception is leaving the line that caused exception ie, `soup=(soup.find(id=math))`

What has gone wrong in my code?

Comment: This does not seem to be a valid python line - `math +=\`i\`` , can you please update the correct code.

Comment: @Anand S Kumar - I have updated the code

Comment: Still not valid python code, how come you are not getting `SyntaxError` ?

Comment: Backticks are valid syntax, but only in 2.7 and below. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673071/what-do-backticks-mean-to-the-python-interpreter-num) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    soup=(soup.find(id=math))
    print(soup.get_text())
```

These lines are overwriting the existing `soup` BeautifulSoup object with an HTML element, which has no `find` method. This means that `soup.find` will always fail for every iteration after the first one.

Try using a different variable name.

```
    element=(soup.find(id=math))
    print(element.get_text())
```