# Python 2.x to 3.x - Append Syntaxerror: how to make it compatibale with Python 3.x from 2.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a very simple question that I am having difficulty tracing down - which implies a very simple answer. I have a slew of scripts written by a slew of people over the last ~12 years or so in python 2x that I am having to port over to python 3x.

After searching and many, many, many fixes I have run into a change that is difficult to track down. I have a syntax error in e.append(lineno, `line`) shown below. Any ideas on how to alter this to make it python 3x compatible would be super useful.

```
    self.__options = {}
    lineno = 0
    e = None                                  # None, or an exception
    while 1:
        line = fp.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        lineno = lineno + 1
        # skip blank lines
        if string.strip(line) == '':
            continue
        # skip lines starting with '['
        if line[0] == '[':
            continue
        # remove anything after '#'
        line = string.split(line, '#')[0]

        # key/value pairs can be seperated by whitespaces
        for opt in string.split(line):
            #if opt in string.whitespace:
            #    continue
            keyval = string.split(opt, '=')
            if len(keyval) == 2:
                self.__options[keyval[0]] = keyval[1]
            else:
                e = ParsingError(fpname)
                e.append(lineno, `line`)

    # if any parsing errors occurred, raise an exception
    if e:
        raise e
```

Comment: What do you intend ``e.append(lineno, `line`)`` to do? (In particular, the backticks around `line`)

Comment: I believe early versions of Python would automatically make a tuple out of multiple parameters to `.append()` (and I think a few similar methods that notionally only need a single parameter).  An extra set of parentheses to make an explicit tuple should fix the problem.

Comment: @khelwood. It's a shortcut for `repr`. One of the arcana.

Comment: @jasonharper well, that wouldn't explain the SyntaxError, rather, it's the backticks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty neat historical syntax.

For backticks, I refer you to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1673087/2988730. The gist is that backticks are shorthand for calling `repr` until they were removed in python 3. They are mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) as the "conversion" operation:

> **`repr`**(*object*)
>
> Return a string containing a printable representation of an object. This is the same value yielded by conversions (reverse quotes). It is sometimes useful to be able to access this operation as an ordinary function...

The append itself is a normal, though [undocumented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.ParsingError) use of the [`ParsingError.append`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/ConfigParser.py#L213) method:

```
def append(self, lineno, line):
```

Since version 3, [`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) had been renamed [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), but still has the [`ParsingError.append`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/configparser.py#L334) method.

So you need a couple of changes:

1. At the beginning of the file, change `from ConfigParser import ParsingError` to

   from configparser import ParsingError
2. Change the line with the error to

   ```
   e.append(lineno, repr(line))
   ```

**Note**

The multiple arguments to `append` evoke, but aren't related to, a behavior of `list.append` that hasn't been supported since python 2.0. You can find a note here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types. Specifically the footnote:

> 2. The C implementation of Python has historically accepted multiple parameters and implicitly joined them into a tuple; this no longer works in Python 2.0. Use of this misfeature has been deprecated since Python 1.4.

Comment: Although considering that `e` comes from `e = ParsingError(fpname)`, and it gets `raise`d later, that probably isn't the actual `list.append` method there. The extra set of parentheses may not be necessary (or this may not be the location that needs the extra parentheses, if whatever `e.append` is ends up calling `list.append`.)

Comment: (Or perhaps that line *was* supposed to append to a list, but it got screwed up while trying to fix other issues.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica. Good catch. I've rewritten the second part significantly